# Spring autowire(by type) returns different instances for different interfaces which are implemented by the same class

Tags: java, spring, autowired

I have two interfaces: **InterfaceA**, **InterfaceB** which are both implemented by a concrete class **TheClass**. These interfaces are autowired in other beans like

```
public class UserA { @Autowired InterfaceA iface;}

public class Framework { @Autowired InterfaceB iface;}
```

The InterfaceA is a user interface exposed to external while InterfaceB is internal one only used by framework itself. I do this in order to isolate at interface level

I expect they are all wired to the same class that is **TheClass**. However, Spring wires them to different instances of **TheClass** even it is a singleton bean. I can understand **InterfaceA** and **InterfaceB** are different types so namely it is legal that wiring to different **TheClass** instances. But one class implementing multiple interfaces is common in Java. How should I handle this case? Autowiring by name is a solution, however, I personally like by type, is there any way of achieving this in by type?

==============================================================================================

***Sorry, it's my bad. I mistakenly created two ApplicationContext in my code. Then the UserA class gets TheClass bean from one ApplicationContext  while Framework class gets from another.
Spring does return the same bean for different interfaces as long as they are implemented by the same bean.***

Comment: interesting; thanks for updating.

Comment: Even better: i think you should posto your conclusion as a valid answer.